# C++17 combine std::async and std::invoke

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to call std::invoke from inside a std::async call but for some reason the compiler don't like it.

Note :
I know I could use a lambda, but I would like to make it work without it

Here is my example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unistd.h>

template <class Fn, class... Args>
inline std::result_of_t<Fn&&(Args&&...)> runTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    try {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch (...) {
        std::terminate();
    }
}

struct A {
        static void g(double x, std::string *s) {
            std::cout << "g() : x = " << x << ", *s = " << *s << std::endl;
            usleep(100);
        }

        static void f(double x, std::string *s) {
            std::invoke(g, x, s); // Working
            auto future1 = std::async(std::launch::async, g, x, s); // Working
            auto future2 = std::async(std::launch::async, std::invoke, g, x, s); // Not working
            auto future3 = std::async(std::launch::async, runTerminateOnException, g, x, s); // Not working
        }
};

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello";
    A::f(10., &s);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51f8c80b0a05fa0e

Comment: You might be confusing `std::invoke` with `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::invoke` is a template function. Therefore simply naming the template name is ambiguous - which of the infinite set of `std::invoke<F, Args...>` do you mean?

You'll need to provide an 'invoker' concrete object.

eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unistd.h>

template <class Fn, class... Args>
inline std::result_of_t<Fn&&(Args&&...)> runTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    try {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch (...) {
        std::terminate();
    }
}

struct invoker
{
    template<class F, class...Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(F&& f, Args&&...args) const {
        return std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct A {
        static void g(double x, std::string *s) {
            std::cout << "g() : x = " << x << ", *s = " << *s << std::endl;
            usleep(100);
        }

        static void f(double x, std::string *s) {
            std::invoke(g, x, s); // Working
            auto future1 = std::async(std::launch::async, g, x, s); // Working
            auto future2 = std::async(std::launch::async, invoker(), g, x, s); // Working now
//          auto future3 = std::async(std::launch::async, runTerminateOnException, g, x, s); // Not working
        }
};

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello";
    A::f(10., &s);
    return 0;
}
```

Same with the template function runTerminateOnException.

Comment: @infiniteLoop yup a lambda with auto args is just an invoker in different clothing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using std::forward() on "args" but not on "f" in the invoker ?

Comment: @infiniteLoop only that it would be unusual to require a function object reference to be an r-value in order to invoke it. There would need to be a meaningful difference in the following 2 calls: `f(arg)` and `std::move(f)(arg)`. I think most of us would agree that this would be surprising to users of the function object.

Comment: `auto` should be `decltype(auto)` on `operator()`.